# Why is a newly inserted component with router-link tag in place of a single item at specific index in v-for list giving error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

When I use router-link tag in dynamically created component (using new Vue({})), it throws error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

found in 
  RouterLink
     Root
```

https://pasteboard.co/IgViweP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzWbF.jpg

But when I use a(link) tag it works fine.
Why is this error coming and how to solve it?

I tried using a(link) tag. It works but kind of removes the feeling of using SPA.

For more clarification here, note-single component emits restore event that triggers restore method

```
<template>

    <ul class="mt-1 p-0 list-unstyled clearfix" v-if="showData && data.data && data.data.length">
        <li v-for="(singleResult, index) in data.data" ref="items" class="list-group-item mb-2">

            <note-single-list-item-deleted v-else-if="singleResult.contentType === 'notes'" :note="singleResult" @restore="restore($event, index)"></note-single-list-item-deleted>

        </li>
    </ul>

</template>

<script>
    import noteSingleListItemDeleted from './content-type-comps-deleted/note-single-list-item-deleted';

    export default {
        components : {
            'note-single-list-item-deleted' : noteSingleListItemDeleted,

        },
        data() {
            return {
                showLoadingAnimation: false,
                showData: false,
                data: {},
                dataRequestSent : false,
                contentType: "notes",
                restoreRequestSent : false,

            }
        },
        methods: {

            getRestoredLinkTemplate(contentType, id) {
                let contentTypeLink;
                let contentTypeToDisplay;
                if(contentType === 'notes') {
                    contentTypeLink = '/note/' + id;
                    contentTypeToDisplay = 'note'
                }

                // this give error ---------------
                let temp = new Vue({
                    template: '<div><router-link :to="link"><p class="m-0 p-0">Go to restored {{ contentTypeToDisplay }}</p></router-link></div>',
                    data () {
                        return {
                            link: contentTypeLink,
                            contentTypeToDisplay : contentTypeToDisplay
                        }
                    }
                });

                // this works ------------------
                // let temp = new Vue({
                //     template: '<div class="m-0 p-0"><a :href="link" target="_blank"><p class="m-0 p-0">Go to restored {{ contentTypeToDisplay }}</p></a></div>',
                //     data () {
                //         return {
                //             link: contentTypeLink,
                //             contentTypeToDisplay : contentTypeToDisplay
                //         }
                //     }
                // });

                return temp;
            },

            restore(item, index){

                if(this.restoreRequestSent) {
                    return;
                }
                this.restoreRequestSent = true;

                axios.post('/trash/restore', item).then((response) => {

                    let newLink = this.getRestoredLinkTemplate(response.data.content_type, response.data.id).$mount().$el;

                    this.$refs.items[index].innerHTML = "";

                    this.$refs.items[index].appendChild(newLink);

                    this.restoreRequestSent = false;

                });
            },

        },
    }
</script>
```

I expect it to show the link in place of recently restored item to navigate to that item.
As in UI, I want this => https://pasteboard.co/IgW7QU1.png / https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCBUB.jpg

Comment: v-else-if is typo. Should be v-if

Comment: where is your `<router-link />`?

Comment: in getRestoredLinkTemplate(contentType, id)  method

Comment: I want this => https://pasteboard.co/IgW7QU1.png  /  https://imgur.com/a/NZiSgPe